# Most Efficient Way to Go From Beginner to Master in a new Language(Java)

Tags: java, resources

I am a Junior Developer Looking to expand his skills by learning Java.

I know that building stuff is the best way to become skilled in a new language.  However,

I would like to know what else aside from this I can do.

I find books a great way to learn a new language.

Can anyone suggest a great book where I would be building applications and learning Java at

the same time?  Right now my primary codebase is VB.NET.  I know that this is a somewhat lesser used language so I would like to devote a lot of my time to Java.

Comment: Don't listen to any of these short-sighted jokers.  The key is to carefully titrate your alcohol intake and find your "[Ballmer Peak](http://xkcd.com/323/)".  If you can successfully maintain yourself at that level, the future is yours for the taking.

Answer (score 3):

Books will help but nothing can substitute actual experience. There's no royal road to knowledge.

However, working with more experienced developers always helps a lot. Communication is key, as even with the best book ever written about Java you can easily lose your way and will struggle to find the way out by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your question reminds me that old "teach C++ yourself in 21 days" [Abstruse Goose](http://abstrusegoose.com/249) strip :

[image]

Yup, nothing beats experience.

Answer (score 1):

The principle is: "The day you start admiring yourself about your proficiency in a programming language beware: the language is obsolete!". The process never stops. This is what makes our job fun.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course no magic formula for learning Java, any more than there is of learning any complex highly intellectual skill (don't pay any attention to the fresh young graduates you write "expert level Java" on their resumes). The best way to learn is to give yourself challenging programming projects to do with the new language.

However books are a very useful supplement to learning through experience. Your first task should be to work through all the general purpose [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), and any of the specialized ones you are interested in.

Once you have done that, the most respected general Java book is unquestionably "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch. If you have read and fully digested that then you are well on the way to being able to call yourself a competent Java programmer.